# Debugging Node.js Express web server in WebStorm hangs

Tags: webstorm

I have a web app written in [Express](https://expressjs.com/) and when I start debugging it through WebStorm it just seems to hang with the following in the console:

```
> NODE_ENV=local node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js
Debugger listening on port 55463.
```

If I try to navigate to localhost in Chrome I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. If I hit the Run instead of Debug button in WebStorm it works fine.

Weird thing is this was working earlier today and I can't think of anything I changed. At one point I had this issue and restarted WebStorm and it resolved the issue, but not anymore.

I'm on WebStorm 2017.3.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround this by changing my `package.json` script for starting the server in debug mode from:

```
NODE_ENV=local gulp build && NODE_ENV=local node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js
```

to:

```
NODE_ENV=local node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js
```

So I need to remember to build the server.js distribution code before starting the debugger.

After this change it never hangs when I start the debugger. Maybe WebStorm doesn't like multiple commands in the script used for debugging.